# How can I pick only specific documents within a collection by using the code below?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so the code below brags the data from 'all' documents within the collection and I replaced doc with doc('Empire_State') and tried to run it but it didn't grab any data. Is there a way to grab a specific document instead of all documents within the collection?

```
const buildingInfo = document.querySelector('#building-list');

function renderBldg(doc){
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let address = document.createElement('span');
    let br1 = document.createElement('BR');
    let floors = document.createElement('span');
    let text1 = document.createTextNode(' floors');
    let br2 = document.createElement('BR');
    let owner = document.createElement('span')
    li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    address.textContent = doc.data().address;
    floors.textContent = doc.data().floors;
    owner.textContent = doc.data().owner;

    li.appendChild(address);
    li.appendChild(br1);
    li.appendChild(floors);
    li.appendChild(text1);
    li.appendChild(br2);
    li.appendChild(owner);


    buildingInfo.appendChild(li);

}

db.collection('default').get().then((snapshot) =>{
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        renderBldg(doc);
    })

})
```

Comment: Do u have a doc named Empire_State? You have to do the same you are doing but db.collection(‘default’).doc(whatever_your_doc_name_is).get().then....

Comment: Yeah I do have a doc named Empire_State. I already tried db.collection(‘default’).doc("Empire_State").get().then... but it didn't work.

Comment: Share me a screenshot of ur collection, I will help I better

Comment: You might want to review the documentation for reading data from the database, then edit the question to show the exact code that doesn't work the way you expect. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: @andresmijares: http://oi68.tinypic.com/2v2fafd.jpg

Comment: yeah, check my answer, it should work

Answer (score 1):

when getting a single doc you dont need to iterate over... so this should be enough

```
db.collection('default').doc('Empire_State').get().then((snap) =>{
   if (snap.exists) {
      console.log(`your doc: `, snap.data())
   }

})
```

Comment: I tried that... still doesn't work..(I tried both snap and snapshot since you used snap instead of snapshot)

Comment: well, according to the documentation it should work, what error are u getting? also, do u have any security rule in place?

Comment: yeah. I set my security rules so that any input/change will be allowed. and regarding error messages, I don't get any error message on my text editor but the info just doesn't show up on my local hosted webpage at all.

Comment: I recommend you to check the docs Doug mentioned, ... it’s reslly to help you with this information

Comment: yeah... will do.